# Why doesn't my form receive simulated "Return" keypress/keydown?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms

My windows form navigates to a website on launch and I also gave the form a button to log me into said website. 
My problem is that now I want that button to press automatically when I run my program. I gave the button a tab index of 0 so I can just simulate the "enter" button when it runs. However, "enter" is not registering on the form. My code is as follows.. ps. im using inputsimulator aka windowsinput from nuget (which works on consoles ) but not on forms

I do not want to use send/get method

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Drawing;
using WindowsInput.Native;
using WindowsInput;

namespace FormLogin
{
    class Program
    {
        [STAThread]
        static void Main()

        {
            var sim = new InputSimulator();
            Application.EnableVisualStyles();
            Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
            Application.Run(new Form1());
            sim.Keyboard.Sleep(3000).KeyDown((VirtualKeyCode.RETURN));
        }
    }
}
```

Actual results- form loads, button not pressed
Expected results- form loads, enter is pressed and I am logged in.

Comment: Have you tried setting a breakpoint on `Application.Run`? I believe the next line is not executed until the `new Form1()` is closed. If you want something to happen when the form loads, put the code in the form constructor or in the `Form_Load` event.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I didn't know the next  line doesn't run until the form instance closes. I am new to c# so i will play around with Form_Load and see if i can make it work

Comment: @RufusL I finally figured it out thank you so much. I was stuck on something where I didn't know the problem was else where.

Comment: my program now is able to press enter once it starts and logs me into a website. How do I now add more code to execute after im logged in so i can auto-navigate via hyperlinks in the webpage? Do i have to use async and await? I assume i cannot just add to form shown
            w3bbrows3r.Navigate("webpage.com");
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            var s = new InputSimulator();
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.RETURN);
            Thread.Sleep(2000);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);
            s.Keyboard.KeyPress(VirtualKeyCode.TAB);

Comment: Why do you assume that won't work? If it doesn't, post a new question

Comment: I see TAB gets pressed because it changes focus away from my login button so Enter (to log me in) is not pressed. I will post it tomorrow when my limit lets me ask again and I still haven't figured it out. thanks for your patience

Answer (score -1):

I believe you need to use KeyUp, not KeyDown. KeyDown is the first event that fires, but usually it's [KeyUp](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/GlobalEventHandlers/onkeyup) (when the user releases a key) that triggers the event.